# Flutter how to map a completed Future object in List map

Tags: dart, flutter

```
Future<List<Future<News>>> getNewsList(skipItems) async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      var responseNewsList = json.decode(response.body);
      newsList = responseNewsList as List;
      var resNewsList = (responseNewsList as List)
          .skip(skipItems)
          .take(20)
          .map((id) =>  this.fetchNewsDetails(id))
          .toList();

      return resNewsList;
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
}

Future<News> fetchNewsDetails(id) async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/$id.json?print=pretty');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      return News.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
}
```

So as the code you can see that I try to get a list of top stories post but the response only return me a list of ids, so I will need call another api to get the post detail, in the way above I will need to use twice `Future Builder` for display the content, the way works but is there anyway for me to wait the response back and have the post result in the mapping function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you want

```
await Stream.fromIterable((responseNewsList as List)
      .skip(skipItems)
      .take(20))
      .asyncMap((id) =>  this.fetchNewsDetails(id))
      .toList();
```

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html

Comment: hmm... I got an error `The method 'asyncMap' isn't defined for the class 'dart.core::Iterable<dynamic>` do I need to change anything other than that line?

Comment: Sorry, didn't look close enought. I assumed `skip` and `take` are applied to a `Stream`. You can make it a stream using `await Stream.fromIterable((responseNewsList as List)
          .skip(skipItems)
          .take(20)).asyncMap(...).toList()`

Comment: OMG! it works! thanks for helping! by the way, the answer missing a close bracket after the `.take(20)`. Thanks for helping again you have made my day!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to Günter's is to replace the manual creation of a stream and make it more explicit if you actually just want the completed Futures instead:

```dart
await Future.wait((responseNewsList as List)
    .skip(skipItems)
    .take(20)
    .map(fetchNewsDetails)
  );
```

Comment: Final `.toList()` is wrong and must be removed, `Future.wait()` returns `Future<List<T>>` by self...
But except this, it is the most relevant and useful answer!

Comment: @Nashev fixed it (and replaced the `map` literal with a tear-off), thx!